# Copying and pasting from emacs terminal

Tags: emacs

So I have a file I open using emacs with 1000+ lines that contains columns of data. Is there a way to highlight everything (all lines) in the file so that I may copy and paste to my internet browser (such as in email)?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: `M-< C-SPC M-> M-w` to copy the whole buffer and middle button click in the browser to paste in the buffer works for me.

Comment: I am using Mac OS X Lion

Comment: @Ben C-x h M-w is shorter :)

Comment: I know C-x is  Control-x, but what is h M-w?

Comment: @jozefg, yes thanks for the trick. @user1821176 `C-x h` (control-x then h) runs the command `mark-whole-buffer` (i.e. emecs style selection) and `M-w` runs `kill-ring-save` (i.e. copy selection)

Comment: It saved it but what function do I do to paste it to my browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> to select everything and copy it.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> selects everything, and <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> will copy whatever is selected.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> `mark-page` you can typically also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to select the page

followed by

<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

to copy the marked region, in this case the entire page.